# @cython.wraparound(False) cast integer CORE GENERATED Error

Tags: cython

In cython when my code is compiled with

```
@cython.wraparound(True)
```

and I use the following cast function to convert (cast) a float to an integer

```
cdef DTYPE_t_I float_int(np.float_t val):
    return <DTYPE_t_I>val
```

it runs ok

BUT

when I turn off

```
@cython.wraparound(False)
```

the code compiles normally and when it runs it gives the following error

```
CORE GENERATED
```

It happens compiling in linux with gcc and windows with MGS

What is wrong? Should it be like this?

Because I am trying to gain speed, I would like to know to switch off these flag.